# Can't modify multidimensional array using .last

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array

Here is my code :

```
var states:[[[Int]]] // I create an empty multidimensional array
states = [[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]] // I give it a value


// Why does here it doesn't work ? ('@ivalue $T11' is not identical to 'Int')
states.last![0][0] = 1

// And here it does ?
states[0][0][0] = 1
```

I am not getting why it triggers me an error in one case and not in the other one ? I thought it would do exactly the same thing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`last` returns the last element, but it doesn't allow you to set a new value. In fact the property implements the `get` only:

```
/// The last element, or `nil` if the array is empty
var last: T? { get }
```

So you cannot use it to modify the array.

Note that in case the returned element is a composite value type (i.e. a struct, like an array or a dictionary), a copy of the actual element stored in the array is returned. So any change made to the element returned by `last` or any of its properties and data is performed on that copy only, without affecting the original array.